# Radioplayer with up-to-date (updated on regularly basis) stations (streams)?

Tags: software-rec, media-player

Up until now I'm using RadioSure as my online radio player, but I'm fed up with their long cycles between updates and the negligence regarding updating radio stations.

Is there an alternative, preferably open-source/freeware, which updates the list of radiostations on a regular basis? And on top of that has A LOT(!!) radio stations? RadioSure has some 12000 odd stations listet (a lot of them duplicates with different sound qualities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my favorite:

**[Spider Player](http://spider-player.com/)** - The Ultimate Music Player

tons of radio stations, automatically updated ... and an incredibly low footprint.

- Internet radio recording
  Spider Player Basic can continuously record any Internet streams for up to 5 minutes to MP3 format.
- Radio Directory
  Discover thousands of radio stations around the globe with fast and easy search in Shoutcast and Icecast radio directories right within Spider Player.

*Spider Player is freeware and portable*

**[Screamer Radio](http://www.screamer-radio.com/features/)** is a Internet Radio player for Microsoft Windows. even more stations and an up-to-date web directory

Why to use Screamer Radio

- It's easy to use
- It's not bloated
- It's ad free
- It has a huge database of radio stations
- It has a cool peak meter ;)
- You can easily record what you're listening to
- You can hide it in the system tray
- You can play back on multiple soundcards

Supported Stream Types

- Shoutcast and Icecast MP3 Streaming
- Icecast OGG Vorbis Streaming
- WMA Streaming
- AAC Streaming

Recording Features

- Recording buffer: start recording in the middle and still save the entire song!
- Direct MP3 Audio stream saving, no loss of quality!
- Direct OGG Vorbis stream saving, no loss of quality!
- Or encode OGG Vorbis as MP3 using Lame
- Encode WMA or AAC to MP3 using Lame

*Screamer is freeware and portable.*

Comment: That's a great start! Keep 'em comin' folks!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Winamp](http://winamp.com) to listen to [SHOUTcast](http://shoutcast.com) servers. They have tons of stations (Currently 33,566) which you can browse via the web. Winamp comes in a free and pro version.